# Send bitmap to image picker / gallery application

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, icons, send

I'm trying to add an option in my app to send an image inside my app to other app like gallery or image picker/selectors. For example, a third-party launcher, which wants to select an icon that is inside my app.

I'm using a RecyclerView grid, to show the list of icons.

This is my code to load the icons:

```
icons = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icons);
list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(iconNames));

loadIcon(list);

private void loadIcon(List<String> list) {
    mThumbs = new ArrayList<>();    

    for (String extra : list) {
        int res = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", p);
        if (res != 0) {
            final int thumbRes = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", p);
            if (thumbRes != 0)
                mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the OnClick of grid item:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bitmap bitmap = null;

try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbs.get(position));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("Icons Picker Error", "Picker error: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}

if (bitmap != null) {
    intent.putExtra("icon", bitmap);
    mContext.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
} else {
    mContext.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
}

mContext.finish();
```

Apparently, icon bitmap is created properly, but when trying to send it to the selector, nothing is sent.

I'm not sure what could be wrong in the code, but I hope someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can display a chooser (all apps capable of performing the task are displayed for the user to select from). here is a code snippet to do that:

```
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app to share the image"));
```

For this to work, you need to pass the Uri of the bitmap. One way of achieving this is to save the bitmap in a temporary file and then use *FileProvider.getUriForFile()* to get the uri of the temp file.

good luck

clive